# What is the length of $EF$ in the following diagram?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, congruences-geometry

[image]

> In triangle $\triangle ABC$, angle $A=50^\circ$ , angle $C=65^\circ$ .
>   Point $F$ is on $AC$ such that, $BF$ is perpendicular to $A$C. $D$ is
>   a point on $BF$ (extended) such that $AD=AB$. E is a point $CD$ such
>   that, AE is perpendicular to $CD$. If $BC=12$, what is the length of
>   $EF$?

Source: [Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2016 Junior Catagory](https://www.matholympiad.org.bd/)

I tried and proved that $ABF \cong AFD$ and $BCF \cong CFD$. I am not able to find any relation of $EF$ with other sides.

Comment: $F$ is the midpoint of $BD$ and $E$ is the midpoint of $CD$. Hence $EF={1\over2}BC$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the congruent triangles you have already found, you can conclude that 
$\triangle ABC \cong \triangle ACD.$
Use the two known angles of $\triangle ABC$ to find the third angle.
You will then be able to show that $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ACD$ are isosceles triangles, and that $E$ is the midpoint of $CD.$

Since $AB = AD,$ triangle $\triangle ABD$ also is isosceles and $F$ is the midpoint of $BD.$

These facts should tell you something about the relationship between $\triangle BCD$ and $\triangle FED,$
after which you can find the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I successfully found that EF = 6. That was a great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Angle $CBA=180°-50°-65°=65°=\angle ACB$, so $AB=AC=AD$. In triangle $BCF$, $CE=BC/2$, $FC=BC\cos 65°$ and $\angle FCE = 65°$, so one can find $FE$ with cosine theorem.